# Cannot mutably borrow in a pattern guard [E0301]

Tags: rust

```
unsafe fn get_sync_handle(pid: u32) -> Option<HANDLE>
{
    let raw_h = OpenProcess(SYNCHRONIZE, 0, pid as DWORD);
    match raw_h
    {
        x if x >= 0 as HANDLE => None,
        x => Some(x)
    }
}

src\lib.rs:411:19: 411:23 error: cannot mutably borrow in a pattern guard [E0301] src\lib.rs:411 x if x >= zero => None
```

Could someone explain to me cause of this error? While I know this is quite contrived example I don't understand why compiler complains, I'm not trying to modify anything, and `raw_h` itself is immutable.

Comment: Looks like a bug in the compiler to me. Or at least the error message is completely confusing. I'd submitted an issue ticket on this if I were you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a self-contained example:

```
type Handle = *mut ();

fn main() {
    let foo = 0 as Handle;
    match foo {
        x if x >= 0 as Handle => None,
        x                     => Some(x)
    };
}
```

Note the error message and *where it points*:

```
<anon>:6:19: 6:30 error: cannot mutably borrow in a pattern guard [E0301]
<anon>:6         x if x >= 0 as Handle => None,
                           ^~~~~~~~~~~
```

It's actually the "null" that is complained about. You can flip the check around, then there won't be any mutability in the match guard.

```
type Handle = *mut ();

fn main() {
    let foo = 0 as Handle;
    match foo {
        x if x as isize >= 0 => None,
        x                    => Some(x)
    };
}
```

Comment: yes, you're right, it's pretty much the same as in my response (without example), I guess it's because I could potentially dereference foo and mutate it since `foo` itself is declared as mutable (but then I'm rust newbie so I'm only guessing).

Answer (score 0):

I already happened to find reason why it doesn't works. It's because [retep998/winapi-rs](https://github.com/retep998/winapi-rs)
which I'm using defines `HANDLE as *mut c_void`, casting to `usize` solves problem.